# Are Kubernetes Helm questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, close-reasons, migration

From time to time I stumble across questions about Helm charts.

Tag information of [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) doesn't contain a clause about what's on- or off-topic.

Based an on excerpt from [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) I *think* they are off-topic:

> KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE
> DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here. A good
> rule of thumb is, if it happens outside the pod, it's probably
> off-topic. If it's about code running inside the pod, it's probably
> OK.

But I'm not sure my understanding is correct, because technically helm charts introduce one more layer of abstraction, that can be considered as programming itself.

Can somebody please help me understand, with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76999547) as an example, what should be done with these questions; when they are on topic and when not? And if some of them are off topic (and decent quality) should they be flagged to be moved to DevOps.SE<sup>1</sup> or somewhere else?

---

<sup>1</sup> : [This answer](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/381/39924) from a moderator on their meta suggests that they aren't against massive migration of related questions, from which I conclude they wouldn't be against single question migrations.

Comment: Your exemple question is a syntax problem at root I think. Would be on topic on [devops.se] but closed as needing details to be answered there as well as here. (Disclaimer: I'm an ex pro-temp devops.se mod)

Comment: @Tensibai, I do believe that all or almost all [helm] questions would be on-topic there. my question was more of "are the off-topic here", or even "are they off-topic here enough to warrant closure or migration".

Comment: Mostly, often not IMHO. There's a fair bit of overlap as [DevOps.se] does accept programming questions related to IAC/IAS SDK, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Most things that intersect with [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) and [go-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-templates) seem like "programming" to me.  The Go `text/template` language has functions, variables, loops, and other things you'd expect out of a programming language.  The highest-scored question with both of these tags as of this writing is [Kubernetes Helm, combine two variables with a string in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278655/kubernetes-helm-combine-two-variables-with-a-string-in-the-middle) and that's very much a programming-101 question.

On the other end of the spectrum, I agree that a lot of the [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) questions are of the form "I'm trying to *deploy* software X with a Helm chart, what values should I provide to...?"  I tend to close these as "not about programming or software development".  ([kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm)[prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prometheus) and [grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grafana) seem to be frequent offenders here for whatever reason.)

Having written this: the question you link to is in fact a [grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grafana) question and is in fact closed as "not about programming", and I agree with this.

I don't think wholesale migrating *all* of the [kubernetes-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) questions to DevOps.SE is right; I think there are enough on-topic questions to make the tag worth keeping.  But I agree with voting to close questions where the operative verb is "deploy" or "configure", and not "build" or "write" or "develop".

Comment: Great, thanks for explanation. Will be voting to close questions about deploying and configuring, especially in mentioned prometheus and grafana tagged questions, since they are basically my scope of interest)

Comment: Please consider adding ontopicness scope clause to tag's excerpt.

Comment: I don't think all configuring questions are necessarily off-topic. I ran into a template with a weird looping syntax and couldn't, for the life of me, figure out how to structure a yaml list of objects that would satisfy the parser. That sounds on-topic per the first paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

Questions about writing charts/templates (e.g. Yaml files) might be on-topic. Otherwise, no I don't see how Kubernetes Helm is on-topic here, especially considering much of Kubernetes itself is also off-topic here.